# NPM package for retrieving native country/region name from country/region code

Tags: javascript, language

I need a package for converting a code like `US` into `United States`. I found [`country-locale-map`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-locale-map), but it only supports converting code into international name.

For example, I need to convert `BR` into `Brasil`. The NPM package `country-locale-map` only outputs `Brazil` (the international form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ECMA-402 standard defines `Intl.DisplayNames`, so no NPM package needed as that is already supported in NodeJS built-ins. Here's an example from developer.mozilla.org:

```
const regionNamesInEnglish = new Intl.DisplayNames(['en'], { type: 'region' });
const regionNamesInTraditionalChinese = new Intl.DisplayNames(['zh-Hant'], { type: 'region' });

console.log(regionNamesInEnglish.of('US'));
// Expected output: "United States"

console.log(regionNamesInTraditionalChinese.of('US'));
// Expected output: "美國"
```